# Why doesn't exec("top"); work on Linux?

Tags: php, linux, exec, top-command

I was trying to execute this command

```
echo exec("top");
```

and

```
echo exec("/usr/bin/top");
```

neither works (returns blank output)

does anybody know why?

Comment: Verify top is installed.

Comment: exec() is probably disabled on your host.

Comment: @hexa: I'm using VPS and this one works http://phpcode.eu/exec/index2.php

Comment: @iLLin: I'm using it on daily basis

Comment: @KingCrunch: did you read my previous comment? I USE IT ON DAILY BASIS

Comment: And can downvoter tell me reason ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because top is an interactive program that is meant to be run on a terminal, not be executed from a script.  You are probably want to run the 'ps' command with arguments which will sort output by cpu utilization.
http://www.devdaily.com/linux/unix-linux-process-memory-sort-ps-command-cpu

Answer (score 8):

You actually can call top and echo its output. Code that worked for me:

```
passthru('/usr/bin/top -b -n 1');
```

-b - running in batch mode

-n 1 - only one iteration

Comment: None of the previous answers work for me but passthru did. Nice.

Comment: This finally works. Also, if -n 1 is removed, top will take input.

Answer (score 6):

It probably works, but `exec()` doesn't return anything. Read the Manual: [`exec()`](http://php.net/function.exec)

```
$output = null;
exec('top', $output);
echo $output;
```

But you have another problem: `top` doesn't exit by itself. You cannot use it here, because you need to send the interrupt-signal (just realized: `q` is ok too).

One solution is to make [`top`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?top) to stop after one iteration

```
$output = null;
exec('top -n 1', $output);
var_dump($output);
```

Comment: I never said anything about `-l 1`. I just tried it myself with `-n 1` and it works fine

Comment: Look here http://phpcode.eu/exec/index2.php - how is it possible that it does work with classic echo exec(); ?

Comment: $output = null;
exec('top -n 1', $output);
print_r($output);
//What's wrong here?

Comment: Without any further information I can't tell anything else then "works fine here". Maybe you need to adjust the path to `top` or something like that (because maybe `$PATH` is not set or something like that). Thats all. And really: Only "Does not work" on nearly every answer does not encourage me to think about it any further.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to put it in a variable :

```
ob_start();
passthru('/usr/bin/top -b -n 1');
$output = ob_get_clean();
ob_clean();
```

Answer (score 0):

I used:

```
$cpu = preg_split('/[\s]+/', shell_exec('mpstat 1 1'));
$cpu = 100-$cpu[42];
```

100% minus the idle time.