# How to print the output of a shell command in php?

Tags: php, shell, unix, terminal

I want to print the output of a command named `jnettop` into an html file.

I am very familiar with `shell_exec()` and sort. 
But it doesnt work as the command that Im using doesnt have a bash mode like top that is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6653567/why-doesnt-exectop-work-on-linux).

The end goal is have a site that I go to and I see the information that jnettop would normally display in terminal. 
[Here](http://jnettop.kubs.info/wiki/) is the link to [jnettops](http://jnettop.kubs.info/wiki/) wiki page.

Answer (score 0):

You might try [passthru()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php) or [exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) with the output argument peresent.

Answer (score 0):

> the command that Im using doesnt have a bash mode like top

Sure it has: `jnettop --display text`.